# how to list framebuffer sizes in 14.04 for grub

Tags: 14.04, grub2, display-resolution

I'm trying to discover my frame buffer size so I can fix my crtl+alt+f# virtual terminals and grub boot size.

It seems that in ubuntu 14.04 **hwinfo --framebuffer** isn't possible becuase **hwinfo** is gone because of hal something or other.

My laptop native resolution is 3840x2160 so my grub menu and virtual terminals are **incredibly** small.  I'd like to lower the resolution to 1920x1080 but I can't find the value I need to put for the grub file "vga=xxx"

Is there another way to list them?

Thanks